# show table when i click on row of other table

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement where I have a table of records of master object.
When I click on a row of master table then another table with related child record should get shown.

Parent Object is **Supplier** And Child Object is **Quote**

Here is my code,

**Visualforce Page**

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="List of All Supplier" columns="2" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="s" value="{!SupplierReturn}" id="supplier">
            <apex:column headerValue="Supplier Name" value="{!s.name}" ondblclick=""/>
            <apex:param name="sParam" value="{!s.id}" assignTo="{!supplierValue}"/>
            <!--</apex:column>-->
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!QuoteReturn}" id="quote">
            <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name" value="{!r.name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class testPageExt {

public List<Quote__c> quoteList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> supllierList {get;set;}
public String supplierValue {get;set;}

    public testPageExt() {
        quoteList = new List<Quote__c>();
        supllierList = new List<Supplier__c>();
    }
    public List<Quote__c> getQuoteReturn() {
        quoteList = [Select id, name ,RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c where RFQ_Supplier__c =:supplierValue ];
         return quoteList;
    }
    public List<Supplier__c> getSupplierReturn() {
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        return supllierList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you are rerendering the quote section or performing any action when a row is clicked. How are you expecting it to redisplay with updated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for tha same would be like this...

**Vf Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="testPageExt" >
<apex:form >
<apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />
<apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/25.0/sprites/1342034628000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css" />

    <apex:pageBlock title="Supplier List" helpTitle="supplier" helpUrl="/apex/testPage" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="List of All Supplier" columns="2" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!supllierList }" var="s" id="supplier">
                <apex:column headerValue="Supplier Name" >
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!quoteaction}" value="{!s.name}" reRender="quote">
                    <apex:param name="sParam" value="{!s.id}" assignTo="{!supplierValue}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>     
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!quoteList}" id="quote">
                <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name" value="{!r.name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class testPageExt {

public List<Quote__c> quoteList {get;set;}
public List<Supplier__c> supllierList {get;set;}
public String supplierValue {get;set;}

    public testPageExt() {
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        system.debug('*********'+supllierList );
        quoteList = null;
        getSupllieraction();
    }


    public List<Supplier__c> getSupllieraction() {
        supllierList =[Select id, Name from supplier__c];
        return supllierList ;
    }

    public void quoteaction() {
        quoteList = [Select id, name ,RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c where RFQ_Supplier__c =:supplierValue ];
    }
}
```